# How can I mount a remote server just like raspbian does it?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mount

I can manually connect to a remote server by going to the File Manager and select "Connect to Server" under the "Go" tab.
Then I can type in the ip and username and I am ready to go. And I dont need to add a password because I have set up ssh-keys.
As shown in the images below:

[image: Raspberry Menu showing pi>Go>Connect to Server] [image: Specify remote folder to connect form]

After that I can access the remote folder at this location:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.178.35,user=user/
```

My question is, how can I achieve the same result, but without the UI, just with the CLI?
(What command is used by the raspberry OS?)
And further, how can I unmount the volume after using it with the CLI?

Thanks for the help : )

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type the following command in the console to connect to the remote server. When you are finished, you can close the connection with the command `exit`.

```
ssh username@address
```

You can find a very detailed description [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-to-connect-to-remote-server-linux-or-windows).

Comment: I don't want to log into it. I want to mount the file system the same way raspbian does it

Comment: For mounting you can simply use [SSHFS (SSH Filesystem)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sshfs.md). This allows you to mount the files over the SSH connection.

Comment: this technicality works... but what is raspbian doing if I press the button? If they would use SSHFS I wouldnt have to install it first

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the comment you wrote in the other answer, I think you're looking for an [SFTP server](https://titanftp.com/2018/11/09/what-is-sftp/), this is basically a server where you can manipulate directories and the files in them remotely by mounting it.

The image you showed however, does show an SSH server, as [@flaxel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340528/8294421) said in his/her answer.

Comment: I just want to know what raspbian is using. And since SSHFS is not installed, I assume they dont use it.

Comment: I am not completely sure about this as I don't have the correct knowledge to know exactly how Raspbian is setting up an SFTP server behind the scenes, I can however, do some research on this.
The default file manager used by Raspbian is [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM), which (along with others) has a built-in SFTP protocol/server. I _think_ (I cannot stress this enough, I am not sure about this), they use that to setup the SFTP server. Read more about how to handle SFTP servers in the Raspbian [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sftp.md)

Comment: and that is was confuses me. They use gvfs (or at least put it in a folder called gvfs) but the command gvfs-mount has to be manually installed. And they say everywhere: go use SSHFS. but I have to install that to... anyways, thanks for trying to help